# Создать задание CRON из PHP

Tags: php, cron

Доброго времени суток.

У меня вопрос такой, реально ли создать задание для CRON непосредственно из PHP? То есть хочется, чтобы при выполнении какого-то скрипта ставилось задание, которое исполнится через 3 дня.

У меня пока один вариант - поставить CRON на каждый день, который будет проверять наличие новых заданий и в случае их нахождения - выполнять. Но это лишние задания CRON, по сути. А хотелось бы создавать только нужные задания, но при этом чтоб их создавал сам скрипт.

Comment: Да и хочу добавить, что не всегда через 3 дня, всегда по разному (но именно в днях), при том первый скрипт может выполниться в любое время, а надо чтоб второй скрипт исполнился ровно через N*24 часов.

Comment: Плюс по моему варианту будут расхождения во времени, в сутки - слишком много, а если каждый час проверять - слишком много нагружается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа непосредственно с кроном через пхп очень не рекомендуется (и даже не знаю, возможна ли).

Самый оптимальный вариант, на мой взгляд, сделать следующим образом:

1) Создать БД и таблицу, в которой будут храниться ваши задания (если нужно, то и другую таблицу или файл, в котором будет лог выполнения).

2) Написать пхп-скрипт, который будет проверять эту таблицу и выполнять скрипты, время которых подошло, но отметки о выполнении еще не стоит.

3) Добавить задание в кроне на запуск этого скрипта, например, каждый час (да хоть, каждые 10 минут или минуту).

В этом случае у вас будут все возможности для полноценной работы и установлении расписания.

По идее, здесь не хватает еще пункта 4 - сделать АПИ для работы с вашей системой (добавление/изменение/удаление заданий, получения списка заданий и т.д.).

P.S. [Вот здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1153) нашел материал по работе с кроном непосредственно с пхп. Есть еще различные способы, через которые можно напрямую поменять файл /etc/crontab , но ИМХО это плохой стиль давать доступ пользователю пхп напрямую работать с кроном.

Comment: Ну я так и сделал в принципе. Но храню не в бд, не хочу к ней обращаться лишний раз, храню задания в файле, кажется, должно быстрее работать, а нагрузку нужно минимизировать. Но и не каждый час, а каждые 12 часов. Как жаль, что в 2016 нельзя это сделать нормально.